# All Dll's not getting signed when create an exe for Windows Ionic App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, electron, ionic3, electron-builder

The generated ionic app is going through security scan check wherein I have observed that in the windows .exe file some of the dll's are not signed.

I have added the certificate details and path in package.json build property and using electron-builder for creating exe.

Sample of pakage.json:

```
"build": {
  "win": {
  "certificateFile": "./certs/certificate.pfx",
  "certificatePassword": "pass",
  "icon": "www/assets/icon/win/win.ico",
  "publisherName": "Publisher",
  "target": [{
    "target": "nsis",
    "arch": ["ia32"]
   }]
  }
}
```

Using following command to check the dll's list :

**sigcheck -e -s -c "C:\Program Files(x86)\appname" > "appname.csv"**

I see some of the dll's and files getting signed, while others are not.

[image]

Is there a way to get all these dlls signed?

Comment: Hey, I'm running into the same problem. Have you found a workaround?